# Why is the appendix title not inserted to the header in twopage documents?

Tags: fancyhdr, appendices, double-sided

I'm writing my thesis in the `twoside` article class and wondered why the title of the appendices wasn't inserted into the `fancyhdr`. After a bit of error searching, I finally found the problem. It's caused by the `twoside` option. In a one sided document, the title is inserted, in a two sided document it isn't.

Why is that, and how could I fix it?

#### Edit

With `\pagestyle{fancy}` the title is also inserted in the header.

---

### MWE

```
\documentclass[11pt, twoside]{article}



% %%%%%%%%
% Preamble
% %%%%%%%%

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{%
    geometry,%
    fancyhdr,%
    lipsum%
}

\usepackage[titletoc, title, header]{appendix}

\geometry{%
    a4paper,%
    top=3cm,%
    bottom=3.5cm,%
    outer=2.5cm,%
    inner=3.5cm,%
    nomarginpar,%
    showframe=false%
}

\fancypagestyle{general}{%
    \fancyhf{}                  % Clean fields
    \fancyhead[R]{\itshape\nouppercase{\rightmark}}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
    \fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
}



% %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Begin the document
% %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

    \pagestyle{general}

    \section{Section}
    \lipsum

    \newpage
    \begin{appendices}
        \section{Foo bar}
        \lipsum[1-2]
    \end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

---

Oh and by the way: Does anybody know how I could add a colon (`:`) between **Appendix A** and **Foo bar**, making the title `Appendix A: Foo bar` instead of `Appendix A  Foo bar`?

Answer (score 2):

Edit: The real 'culprit' is the change of `\sectionmark` in `appendices`, see the 2nd solution below.

Two-side setups require specification of `LE,RO` and `LO,RE`, i.e. `left even`, `right odd` and `left odd`,`right even` settings for `\fancyhead` etc.

Using `\fancyhead[R]` isn't enough since `\rightmark` has a different meaning in `twoside` option.

Also, don't use `\usepackage{geometry,fancyhdr}` in a row, use one line per package, otherwise you can't specify options to one package that are not known by another one.

Add `headheight=20pt` for example to prevent the warning by `fancyhdr`.

```
\documentclass[11pt, twoside]{article}

% %%%%%%%%
% Preamble
% %%%%%%%%

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{geometry}

\geometry{%
  headheight=20pt,
    a4paper,%
    top=3cm,%
    bottom=3.5cm,%
    outer=2.5cm,%
    inner=3.5cm,%
    nomarginpar,%
    showframe=false%
}


\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage[titletoc, title,header]{appendix}


\fancypagestyle{general}{%
  \fancyhf{}                  % Clean fields
  \fancyhead[LE,RO]{\itshape\nouppercase{\rightmark}}
  \fancyhead[LO,RE]{\itshape\nouppercase{\leftmark}}
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
  \fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
}



% %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Begin the document
% %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{general}

\section{Section}
\lipsum

\clearpage

\begin{appendices}
  \section{Foo bar}
  \lipsum[1-10]
\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

Using an new version of `appendices`, by changing the `\sectionmark` macro that is redefined in `appendices` from `appendix` code already:

```
\documentclass[11pt, twoside]{article}

% %%%%%%%%
% Preamble
% %%%%%%%%

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{geometry}

\geometry{%
  headheight=20pt,
    a4paper,%
    top=3cm,%
    bottom=3.5cm,%
    outer=2.5cm,%
    inner=3.5cm,%
    nomarginpar,%
    showframe=false%
}


\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage[titletoc, title,header]{appendix}


\fancypagestyle{general}{%
  \fancyhf{}                  % Clean fields
  \fancyhead[R]{\itshape\nouppercase{\rightmark}}
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
  \fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
}


\makeatletter

\renewenvironment{appendices}{%
  \@resets@pp
  \if@dotoc@pp
    \if@dopage@pp              % both page and toc
      \if@chapter@pp           % chapters
        \clear@ppage
      \fi
      \appendixpage
    \else                      % toc only
       \if@chapter@pp          % chapters
         \clear@ppage
       \fi
      \addappheadtotoc
    \fi
  \else
    \if@dopage@pp              % page only
      \appendixpage
    \fi
  \fi
  \if@chapter@pp
    \if@dotitletoc@pp \@redotocentry@pp{chapter} \fi
  \else
    \if@dotitletoc@pp \@redotocentry@pp{section} \fi
    \if@dohead@pp
      \def\sectionmark##1{%
        \if@twoside
        \markright{\@formatsecmark@pp{##1}}
        \else
        \markright{\@formatsecmark@pp{##1}}{}
        \fi}
    \fi
    \if@dotitle@pp
      \def\sectionname{\appendixname}
      \def\@seccntformat##1{\@ifundefined{##1name}{}{\csname ##1name\endcsname\ }%
        \csname the##1\endcsname\ifnum0=\pdfstrcmp{##1}{section}:\fi\quad}
    \fi
  \fi}{%
  \@ppsaveapp\@pprestoresec}
\makeatother

% %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Begin the document
% %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{general}

\section{Section}
\lipsum

\clearpage

\begin{appendices}
  \section{Foo bar}
  \lipsum[1-10]
\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This does only work with `\leftmark`. I however don't use `\leftmark` but only `\rightmark` :/ Is there a way to still get it working?

Comment: @Sam: I've provided a second solution, but in my point of view, you're misusing `\rightmark` here

Comment: Thank you! I went for a more simple solution than your redefinition. I created a second pagestyle named `appendix` and added it to the hook called with `\begin{appendices}`.

Comment: @Sam: That's what I have done in my version zero (not shown here) but I was unsatisfied with it...

Comment: Any specific reason?